# Changing batch text format

Tags: text, rename, batch-rename

i have around 900 lines of text in this format:
`AddTextEntry("TextHere", "TextHere")`
.. i want to rename these to this format: `{model = "TextHere", vehicleName = "TextHere"},` while keeping all of the original text in place which is in this example `TextHere`.

is this possible? since doing them one by one for 900-1000 lines is a time consuming job. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, totally possible. Are you using Windows or Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a copy of the original file.

Open the original file in Notepad. You can use Sublime Text or another text editor also.

Do find..replace in Notepad by clicking Edit > Replace.

- In Find what, type this: `AddTextEntry("`
- In Replace with, type this: `{model = "`
- Click Replace All

That way, you replace AddTextEntry with model.

Go to the top of the file. Do find..replace again.

- In Find what, type this: `", "`
- In Replace with, type this: `vehicleName = "`
- Click Replace All

That way you add vehicleName before the 2nd text.

Go to the top of the file. Do find..replace again.

- In Find what, type this: `")`
- In Replace with, `"}`
- Click Replace All

That way, you change the last close parenthesis with close curly brace.

Review the file. If all looks good, Save the file.

Comment: thank you very much thats what i'm looking for. i did use `", vehicleName = "` instead of `vehicleName = "` because i needed a comma before the 2nd text. appreciate the help thanks again.